Is it possible to add nodes/object when OPC UA Server is running - not to lose data and connectivity to OPC UA?
Is it possible to add nodes/object when the OPC UA Server is running so as not to lose data and connectivity to OPC UA? I have critical systems that need OPC UA Server availability all the time, and maybe sometimes I will need to add new OPC UA objects and nodes.
I tried to add objects from the Client side when the server wass running, but it was unsuccessful, so I'm not sure if it's possible.

What have you tried so far? Can you give us any code that shows the issue?

That depends entirely on the Server - whether it supports Node Management services at all, and what happens if it does.
